# BindigResult.hasErrors It doesn't work Spring frameworkd validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working with the Spring Framework, I have a model mapped to a controller with which I am trying to do some validations with the annotations offered by Spring, I use the BindingResult hasErrors() interface and also the @Validate annotation, however although I leave fields empty in my models (and specifies the @NotEmpty annotation) I can't get the hasErrors to change its state, it stays false. Am I forgetting something?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Clientes")
public class Cliente {

@Id
@Column(name= "ID_cliente") 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer idCliente;

@Column(name= "Productos_cliente", nullable = true)
private String productosCliente;

@Column(name= "Primer_nombre")
@NotEmpty(message = "El nombre no puede estar vacio")
private String primerNombre;

@Column(name= "Segundo_nombre")
@NotEmpty
private String segundoNombre;

@Column(name= "Primer_apellido")
@NotEmpty
private String primerApellido;

@Column(name= "Segundo_apellido")
@NotEmpty
private String segundoApellido;

@Column(name= "Ciudad_cliente")
private String ciudadCliente;

@Column(name= "Direccion_cliente")
private String direccionCliente;

@Column(name= "Correo_electronico") 
@NotEmpty
private String email;

@Column(name= "Contraseña")
@NotEmpty
private String contraseña; 


public Cliente(String productosCliente, String primerNombre, String segundoNombre, String primerApellido, String segundoApellido, String email, String contraseña ){

    this.productosCliente = productosCliente;
    this.primerNombre = primerNombre;
    this.segundoNombre = segundoNombre;
    this.primerApellido = primerApellido;
    this.segundoApellido = segundoApellido;
    this.email = email;
    this.contraseña = contraseña;

}


/**
 * @return Integer return the idCliente
 */
public Integer getIdCliente() {
    return idCliente;
}

/**
 * @param idCliente the idCliente to set
 */
public void setIdCliente(Integer idCliente) {
    this.idCliente = idCliente;
}

/**
 * @return String return the productosCliente
 */
public String getProductosCliente() {
    return productosCliente;
}

/**
 * @param productosCliente the productosCliente to set
 */
public void setProductosCliente(String productosCliente) {
    this.productosCliente = productosCliente;
}

/**
 * @return String return the primerNombre
 */
public String getPrimerNombre() {
    return primerNombre;
}

/**
 * @param primerNombre the primerNombre to set
 */
public void setPrimerNombre(String primerNombre) {
    this.primerNombre = primerNombre;
}

/**
 * @return String return the segundoNombre
 */
public String getSegundoNombre() {
    return segundoNombre;
}

/**
 * @param segundoNombre the segundoNombre to set
 */
public void setSegundoNombre(String segundoNombre) {
    this.segundoNombre = segundoNombre;
}

/**
 * @return String return the primerApellido
 */
public String getPrimerApellido() {
    return primerApellido;
}

/**
 * @param primerApellido the primerApellido to set
 */
public void setPrimerApellido(String primerApellido) {
    this.primerApellido = primerApellido;
}

/**
 * @return String return the segundoApellido
 */
public String getSegundoApellido() {
    return segundoApellido;
}

/**
 * @param segundoApellido the segundoApellido to set
 */
public void setSegundoApellido(String segundoApellido) {
    this.segundoApellido = segundoApellido;
}

/**
 * @return String return the ciudadCliente
 */
public String getCiudadCliente() {
    return ciudadCliente;
}

/**
 * @param ciudadCliente the ciudadCliente to set
 */
public void setCiudadCliente(String ciudadCliente) {
    this.ciudadCliente = ciudadCliente;
}

/**
 * @return String return the direccionCliente
 */
public String getDireccionCliente() {
    return direccionCliente;
}

/**
 * @param direccionCliente the direccionCliente to set
 */
public void setDireccionCliente(String direccionCliente) {
    this.direccionCliente = direccionCliente;
}

/**
 * @return String return the email
 */
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

/**
 * @param email the email to set
 */
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

/**
 * @return String return the contraseña
 */
public String getContraseña() {
    return contraseña;
}

/**
 * @param contraseña the contraseña to set
 */
public void setContraseña(String contraseña) {
    this.contraseña = contraseña;
}
```

}

Controller:

```
@Controller
@Validated
public class FormController {

@Autowired
ClienteServices service; 

@GetMapping("/register")
public String formLoggin(Model model, Cliente cliente, BindingResult result)
{

    model.addAttribute("Title", "Registro");
    model.addAttribute("cliente", cliente);
   
    return "register";
}   

@PostMapping("/register")
public String sendForm(@Valid Cliente cliente, BindingResult send, Model model)
{   
    model.addAttribute("data", "Registro");
    
    if(send.hasErrors()){  <-- Does not evaluate this condition
        
        return "register";
    }
    model.addAttribute("cliente", cliente);

    
    return "dataUser";
}
```

}

register.html:

```
<body>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-width: 500; min-height: 800; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
  
    <h3 th:text="${Title}"></h3>

    <form th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${cliente}" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="Primer nombre">Primer nombre</label>
            <div>
                <input id="username" name="username" type="text" th:field="*{primerNombre}">
                <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('primerNombre')}" th:errors="*{primerNombre}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="Primer apellido">Segundo nombre</label>
            <div>
                <input id="Secondname" name="Secondname" type="text" th:field="*{segundoNombre}">
                <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('segundoNombre')}" th:errors="*{segundoNombre}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="Primer apellido">Primer apellido</label>
            <div>
                <input id="Surname" name="Surname" type="text" th:field="*{primerApellido}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="Segundo apellido">Segundo apellido</label>
            <div>
                <input id="secondSurname" name="secondSurname" type="text" th:field="*{segundoApellido}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="Email">Correo electrónico</label>
            <div>
                <input id="Email" name="email" type="email" th:field="*{email}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="contraseña">Contraseña</label>
            <div>
                <input id="contraseña" name="password" type="password" th:field="*{contraseña}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="contraseña">Ciudad</label>
            <div>
                <input id="City" name="City" type="text" th:field="*{ciudadCliente}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="contraseña">Dirección</label>
            <div>
                <input id="Dir" name="Dir" type="text" th:field="*{direccionCliente}">
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your dependencies... Wild guess not using `spring-boot-starter-validation` but messing around with `validation-api` yourself and either not including an implementation `hibernate-validator` or using the wrong implementation `hibernate-validator` version 7 .

Comment: In my controller I make use of import *import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;* and *import javax.validation.Valid;*
for my model i am using *javax.validation.constraints* Is there something wrong with these libraries?

Comment: Please answer the questions asked... As stated I suspect you haven't included said library and only have the API (the one providing the annotations) n**not** an implementation actually handling those. Which you generally get from messing around with dependencies yourself.

Comment: You are right, I had not implemented the library that you describe. I find it curious that I can implement annotations and methods that are not included in the dependencies of in my project without throwing an error message, including it in my dependencies solved my problem, thank you very much.

Comment: Annotations are nothing more then metadata, the `javax.validation` stuff is a documented API just like JPA. You can add `@Entity` without having an implementation for JPA but it won't do anything because well no implementation. The same applies here you can add the annotation but if there is nothing that understands those annotations nothing will work. Hence use `spring-boot-starter-validation` which will pull in both the API and an implementation (`hibernate-validator` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Every thing seems to be fine. Try changing your controller this way . Create a new object when sending it to the form like below instead of sending it through parameter as it might not be able to bind object properly:

```
@GetMapping("/register")
public String formLoggin(Model model, BindingResult result)

{

model.addAttribute("Title", "Registro");
model.addAttribute("cliente",new cliente()); //change this line

return "register";
}   



@PostMapping("/register")
public String sendForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("cliente") Cliente cliente, BindingResult send, Model model)
{   
    model.addAttribute("data", "Registro");

if(send.hasErrors()){  <-- Does not evaluate this condition
    
    return "register";
}
model.addAttribute("cliente", cliente);


return "dataUser";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a result from only including the `javax.validation` API and not an implementation. You probably have something like the following in your depenendencies list.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This is only the API not an implementation. This is much like including the JPA `jakarta.persistence-api` and expect JPA to work (but you still need an implementation like Hibernate ORM). For the validation this is the same you need an implementation, mostly used is `hibernate-validator`. So you could add

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**NOTE:** You have to use version 6.x as 7+ is for the new Jakarta Validation API which isn't supported yet (as of Spring Framework 6 / Spring Boot 3 it will).

However as you are already using Spring Boot I would strongly encourage you to use.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This will include both the API and an implementation (the aformentioned `hibernate-validator` one). It will make sure you have a compatible version for this version of Spring / Spring Boot.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of annotating with '@NotEmpty' you can follow this method:

@Column(name= "Correo_electronico", nullable = false)
private String email;

When you use this method either Jpa or Hibernate will throw an error if the value is empty.

Comment: He wants to use validation not fail on persisting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).